# How to use elasticsearch to search for 2 strings at once?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm trying to use elasticsearch to find multiple terms at once.

More specifically, when a user enters a search term like "quake 2", I want elasticsearch to match "quake 2" and "quake ii". So that it matches the result if the games is stored in the system with roman numerals.

I will be using PHP to detect when integers exist in the search term, and then generate the it's counterpart with the roman numerals included, which should be straight forward, so I wasn't looking for help with that.

It's when it comes down to doing the lookup of two strings at once using elasticsearch where I hit a brick wall.

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
$json = '{
            "query" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "title" : [ "quake", "crysis" ],
                        "minimum_should_match" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }';
$searchParams['index'] = 'thegamesdb';
$searchParams['type']  = 'game';
$searchParams['body'] = $json;
$elasticResults = $client->search($searchParams);
```

The above behaves as expected and returns a list of results that include quake and halo, with fairly sane seaach scores for each.

But when I attempt to use the above query to search for "quake 2" and "quake ii" at the same time, I get absolutely no hits? In fact I've determined that it seems to be the inclusion of the spaces between the title and number that is throwing elastic search off.

```
$json = '{
            "query" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "title" : [ "quake 2", "quake ii" ],
                        "minimum_should_match" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }';
```

If spaces aren't allowed in a "terms" query, then how am I supposed to be performing this type of search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the query into two.use bool query should condition and match query to get appropriate result.
match query works because the match query are analyzed and constructed again by ES.

```
     {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "match": {
                      "title": "quake 2"
                   }
               },
               {
               "match": {
                  "title": "quake ii"
               }
               }
            ]
        }
        }
    }
```

i ve tried it.. it worked..
HOpe it helps..!

Comment: Works well! Thanks for the answer!

It found 281 hits in my games db, only 9 of which it felt suitable to return, 7 of them were all matches for quake, with the top 2 of them being exact matches for "quake ii" but it did return the following two at the end: "Raiden II" & "Driver 2".

I tried changing the "should" to "must" and I get exactly the same as above without the last 2 matches that didn't contain the word quake.

So I think for my purposes I'll be using your answer, but with "must" instead of "should".

Thanks very much for the code! +1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
"terms" : {
    "title" : [ "quake", "2", "ii" ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 2
}
```

Or is that being a bit naive?

Comment: This worked well, and provided a much more precise set of results over the accepted answer, just giving me 2 EXACT matches, which is nice. However, it would require me to manually split the seach term into an array of individual words with the integer and roman numerals added at the end, and then have to calculate the minimum that should match myself, which could be less than ideal.

A good answer, but I will keep it on the back burner.

Thanks for the answer though!